# Get the element after the absolute xpath

Tags: python, html, selenium

In my dashboard, there is a value I want to get. To find the value I have used the code
[image]

The code to get the xpath is

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/input')
```

What I am not able to get is the number 49806. In the HTML structure what is that number and how can I  get it. With get_attribute() I have tried all kinds of combinations with no luck.

By the way with find_element_by_id didn't work

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/input').get_attribute("value")
```

Comment: Can you provide a link to that page?

Comment: It seems to be a text, not a value since it is a `h2`, not `input`. Also such a long xpath in 99.9999% cases aren't work

Comment: Have you tried `.text`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use chrome browser you can download xpath helper extension from this [link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xpath-helper/hgimnogjllphhhkhlmebbmlgjoejdpjl) it will show the exact xpath and also it's better if you recode your xpath like this:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//html//body//div//div//div//div[3]//div[1]//div//div//div[1]//div[2]//div//div//div[2]//div//div//div//div[1]//input').get_attribute("value")
```

Comment: That is a great help. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

try with `CSS_SELECTOR`

```
h2_value = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("h2[id='content-companies']").text
print(h2_value)
```

or

```
h2_value = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("h2[id='content-companies']").get_attribute('innerHTML')
    print(h2_value)
```